# How to make a table row if no data found?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php 
    include "db.php";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $search_date = $_POST['search'];
    }

    $show_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM data_input where input_date = '$search_date' ");
    // var_dump($show_result);
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($show_result);
    echo $row_count;

    if ($show_result){
        ?> 

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>items</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>cost</th>
                <th>person</th>
            </tr>       
        <?php
    }
    else{

        if ($row_count == 0) {?>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <?php echo "no data found"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php
        }

    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($show_result)){?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row->id ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row->input_date ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->input_items ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->input_description ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$".$row->input_cost ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->input_person ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php


    }?>
    </table>

    <a href="index1.php" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
    <?php

?>
```

It is a search result page.A simple form which contain a search box and a submit button. At first a date input and query found data then show data in the table but if no data found nothing show in the table. How can I fix this ?Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `if ($row_count == 0)` in the `else` branch of the `if ($show_result)`.
That is not correct, as `mysqli_query` returns false only if there's an error. Not if there simply are no rows in the result.

Solution: move the `if ($row_count == 0)` block up to right after the creation of the table header.

```
    if ($show_result){
        ?> 

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>items</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>cost</th>
                <th>person</th>
            </tr>       
        <?php
        if ($row_count == 0) {?>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <?php echo "no data found"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php
        }

    }
    else{
    }
```

(Then the else block is empty, so you could remove it in this case, or you could echo some diagnostics about what went wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

You should create table before looping the rows, after that check number of rows

- if **zero** then show your table row `else loop` it using while.
  so below I have done it .

  id
              date
              items
              description
              cost
              person

  ```
      <?php
      if ($row_count == 0) {
              ?>

              <tr>
                  <td colspan="6">
                      <?php echo "no data found"; ?>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          <?php
          } else {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($show_result)) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <?php echo $row->id ?>
                  </td>
                  <td><?php echo $row->input_date ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row->input_items ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row->input_description ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "$" . $row->input_cost ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row->input_person ?></td>
              </tr>

          <?php
          }
      }?>
  </table>
  <a href="index1.php" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your while loop code with below code. If no data is found then string 'not found' will be displayed for any row. Also I have used mysqli_fetch_assoc in place of mysqli_fetch_object.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_result)){ ?>
    <?php if(!empty($row)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <?php array_key_exists('id', $row) && $row['id'] != "" ? $id = $row['id']: "not found"; echo $id; ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php array_key_exists('input_date', $row) && $row['input_date'] != "" ? $input_date = $row['input_date']: "not found"; echo $input_date; ?></td>
                <td><?php array_key_exists('input_items', $row) && $row['input_items'] != "" ? $input_items = $row['input_items']: "not found"; echo $input_items; ?></td>
                <td><?php array_key_exists('input_description', $row) && $row['input_description'] != "" ? $input_description = $row['input_description']: "not found"; echo $input_description; ?></td>
                <td><?php array_key_exists('input_cost', $row) && $row['input_cost'] != "" ? $input_cost = $row['input_cost']: "not found"; echo "$".$input_cost; ?></td>
                <td><?php array_key_exists('input_person', $row) && $row['input_person'] != "" ? $input_person = $row['input_person']: "not found"; echo $input_person; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php }else if(empty($row)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <?php echo "not found";   ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo "not found";   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "not found";   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "not found";   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "not found";   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "not found";   ?></td>
            </tr>        
<?php } }?>
```